# BIND9 DNS server not resolving recursive lookups on a different subnet

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, subnet

I've setup an Ubuntu 10.04 BIND9 DNS server in my companies server room so that it has a redundant network, power supply, etc... It shares that room with 2 other servers. If I do an `nslookup` from those 2 servers to `gmail.com` it respond with a Non-authoritative answer without a problem. If I ask it to resolve an internal name it will also respond correctly.

I have two offices, A and B that are connected to that server room through a VPN. A normal windows laptop can resolve an internal name correctly, but when I try to resolve `gmail.com` it says `*** UnKnown can't find gmail.com: Query refused`.

I've haven't changed any of the options except add this to the forwarders:  `8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;`

Since this happens in both of my offices, but not in the server room I suspect it has something to do with our subnets. The server room is in th 10.0.2.x/24 subnet, office A is in the 10.0.5.x/24 subnet and office B is in the 10.0.4.x/24 subnet. Am I on the right track or is this totally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change option 'recursion' and 'allow-recursion' for server or view. Set recursion to 'yes'. allow-recursion defines list of IP-address which are allowed to issue recursive queries. You could do this:

```
allow-recursion { 10.0.2.0/24;10.0.4.0/24;10.0.5.0/24 };
```

Comment: You are right, acorrding to http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html

If recursion yes; (default) then, if allow-recursion is NOT present, defaults to allow-query-cache {localnets; localhost;};. Local cache access permitted to localnets and localhost only.